# Getting [Char] instead of IO() String

Tags: string, haskell

I'm a new to Haskell. I'm reading an input string (a) and want to return a string when I find a character (e) inside. Now my whole source code:

```
a = "b,b,b,b/b,b,b/b,b,b,b/e,e,e/w,w,w,w/w,w,w/w,w,w,w"
n = length a

simpleCase n =
    case n of
        'a' -> "hey cutie"

eLoopCase i =
    if i < n
        then do
            let char = a !! i
            case char of
                'e' -> putStr $ "(" ++ "found an e" ++ "),"
                'w' -> return ()
                'b' -> return ()
                ',' -> eLoopCase (i+1)
                '/' -> eLoopCase (i+1)
            if (char == ',' || char == '/') == False
                then eLoopCase (i+1)
                else return ()
        else return ()
```

simpleCase gives me back a string but eLoopCase gives me an IO() back. It works, however I'd like for eLoopCase to give an String back so I can work on it.

```
:t simpleCase 
simpleCase :: Char -> [Char]
:t eLoopCase 
eLoopCase :: Int -> IO ()
```

I understand that this has something to do with monads,`then do` and `putStr`, this is where my understanding ends. Removing `do` gives a parse error.

Comment: Type signatures, please. And why not remove some of the case-clauses that aren't relevant to the problem?

Comment: Instead of put all of your code here, please make [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not *nomads* but *monads*.

Comment: fixed, sorry about that. 
@leftaroundabout I included what ':t' returned, or do you mean for me to define them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad you've decided to try to learn Haskell. You can do a lot better than eLoopCase. I'll tell you how, but first I'll explain the problem you were having in your original question and how you fixed it.

As originally written, eLoopCase is has a type `Int -> IO ()`, meaning it is a function which takes an `Int` and returns an input output action. IOW, the type tells you that if you give it a number it will do *something*. If you look at the code you can see that that something is just printing out strings, but it could have been almost anything.

In your answer, you rewrote `eLoopCase` to construct strings directly via the `++` operator, instead of printing them out to the terminal via putStr. This is the reason your rewritten function has the type that it does. It also explains why you no longer need the `return ()` statements, which are the "Do nothing while returning a `()` value" IO actions.

I hope that clears things up a little. That said, `eLoopCase` can be tremendously improved.

Haskell programs are efficiently written when the control logic matches the data structure. For instance, this program is iterating through a list. A list is defined as the data which is either an empty list or an element and more list, as seen in the declaration below.

```
data List a = []
            | a : List a
```

Consequently, programs which iterate through a list will be based on decisions for those two constructors. For example (using the synonym `String` for `[Char]`), `eLoopCase` can be rewritten as

```
eLoopCase' :: String -> String
eLoopCase' []     = ""
eLoopCase' (a:as) = evalCase a ++ eLoopCase' as

evalCase a = case a of
  'e' -> "(" ++ "found an e" ++ "),"
  'w' -> ""
  'b' -> ""
  ',' -> ""
  '/' -> ""
  _   -> ""
```

Notice `eLoopCase'` needs to be fed `a` as an input as it is no longer hard coded into the body of the function--a good thing. It also does away with the index `i` and errors arising from using `!!` (try calling `eLoopCase (-1)`).

Having practice in writing recursive functions such as `eLoopCase'` is a good start. An evolution in programming is to see what you are intending to do with that loop and applying appropriate patterns.

For instance, since you want to evaluate every element in a list by a certain function, use a `map`. Specifically `map evalCase` to go from a list of characters to your list of strings, then use `concat` to append all those lists together:

```
eLoopCase'' = concat . map evalCase
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, the code you posted doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks, you used a lot of functions I thought of using but couldn't!

Answer (score 4):

`eLoopCase` is returning nothing because you have `return ()` at all the "ends" of it. I think you're after something like this (Notice appending the current character to the result of the recursive call in the `x == 'w' || x == 'b'` branch):

```
a :: String
a = "b,b,b,b/b,b,b/b,b,b,b/e,e,e/w,w,w,w/w,w,w/w,w,w,w"

eLoopCase :: String -> IO String
eLoopCase [] = return []
eLoopCase (x:xs)
  | x == 'e' = do
      putStrLn "(found an e)"
      return [x]
  | x == ',' || x == '/' =
      eLoopCase xs
  | x == 'w' || x == 'b' = do
      rest <- eLoopCase xs
      return (x : rest)
  | otherwise = do
      putStrLn ("Encountered invalid character: " ++ show x)
      return []
```

General problems with your code:

- The program you wrote is very imperative in style. This is something I would urge you to try to move away from while writing Haskell.
- Prefer pattern matching on lists over indexing with `!!`.

I should note that the function I provided has flaws of its own. It presupposes that the strings provided to it will only consist of a couple different chars. A way to improve it would be to add an `otherwise` branch to the guards. (Edit: Added to the snippet above)

I think it's also worth pointing out that this function really need not depend on IO at all to work. Look into other "pure" alternatives for doing error handling/reporting such as `Either`, `Maybe`, and `Writer`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into pattern matching and imperative style. I was looking for a way to keep iterating on the whole list after I found an e. For example the answer I posted returns `(found an e),(found an e),(found an e),`. Also the type of eLoopCase is IO String and I'm looking for [Char]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've answered my own question. The following seems to work:

```
a = "b,b,b/b,b,b/b,b,b,b/e,e,e/w,w,w,w/w,w,w/w,w,w,w"
n = length a

eLoopCase i =
    if i < n
        then
            case a !! i of
                'e' -> "(" ++ "found an e" ++ ")," ++ eLoopCase (i+1)
                'w' -> "" ++ eLoopCase (i+1)
                'b' -> "" ++ eLoopCase (i+1)
                ',' -> eLoopCase (i+1)
                '/' -> eLoopCase (i+1)
        else ""
```

I'm still curious as to what happened.

Comment: What happened is haskell is hostile to "printf debugging" from pure functions.